# Accessing to a multidimensional PHP array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-ui-dialog

I want to show a jQuery dialog with details of one row in the table (that only shows part of information). This is an example of what I want to do.

The problem: When the image of 'View more details' of a row is clicked, the JS function receives the id of the row clicked. I can't assign  to JS variable 'data' as I did in the HTML part of the code. How can I solve this? Is a good way to do it?

```
<script>
    $(function() {    
        $( "#dialog" ).dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            height: 400,
            width: 600,
            buttons: [{
                text: "Close",
                click: function() {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }]
        });

        $(".details").click(function(){
            $("#dialog").empty();
            var i = $(this).attr('id');
            var data = <?=$cars[i]['price']?>;
            $("#dialog").append("<p>Car:"+data+"</p>");
            $("#dialog").dialog("open");
        });
    });
</script>

<table>
    <?php for($i = 0; $i < count($cars); $i++) { ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?=$cars[$i]['model']?></td>
            <td><?=$cars[$i]['colour']?></td>
            <td> 
                <img class="details" id="<?=$i?>" style="cursor: pointer;" src="http://localhost/ci/public/images/details.png" width="40" height="40" alt="Details"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    <?php } ?>
</table>
```

Comment: What is it supposed to do?

Comment: Based on what I am guessing you are trying to do, the easiest way to do what (I think) you are trying to do is by adding data attributes to your `img` tag from the php side. your click handler can read them with jquery's `data` method call

Comment: @TimSeguine I want to do something similar to this http://aspsnippets.com/demos/671/ but I have some data that is not displayed in the table.

Comment: Your click function doesn't really make sense as it is defined. the line `var data = <?=$cars[i]['price']?>;` will be interpreted by php as `var data = <?=$cars["i"]['price']?>;`, which is not what I think you meant.

Comment: @TimSeguine Yes! This line causes the problem. What I should do to solve it?

Comment: See my answer for one possible solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to use data that is on the server on the client without any code to send it to the client. You have to have a way to get the data from php to javascript. Here is one alternative, which uses HTML data attributes.

In your image tag do this:

```
 <img class="details" id="<?=$i?>" data-price="<?=htmlentities($cars[$i]['price'])?>" style="cursor: pointer;" src="http://localhost/ci/public/images/details.png" width="40" height="40" alt="Details"/>
```

This just saves some data in a form that the client can read easily. `htmlentities` is there just for safety in case the variable contains quote characters (intentionally or not)

I should point out that there is no explicit need for the id attribute at this point unless you are using it for something else.

Then you can change your click function to the following (from the top of my head, not tested, consult the documentation for `.data()`):

```
$(".details").click(function(){
        $("#dialog").empty();
        var data = $(this).data('price');
        $("#dialog").append("<p>Car:"+data+"</p>");
        $("#dialog").dialog("open");
    });
```

Comment: Finally, this solution works. I don't need htmlentities because I have all the data that I want to show in the cars array. Thanks Tim!

Answer (score 1):

There are many way to achieve this few are:

1) If the data is dynamic then uses Ajax

2) If static then any of the below can be used -

- a) Store php array info js array and retrieve it using Key by making the array key as row id and fetch data from array on onClick of the row.
- b) If you want to avoid arrays then -

  - i) Create unique div with info that need to be displayed for every row. Default hide it on click unhide it and show it as dialog.
  - ii) Create a js function with an argument and enable dialog in it with the information passed to it as an argument. For every row call this function on onClick event by passing the info as an argument.